# Does contents of partitions in Spark changes after shuffling?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Does the initial content of each partition changes once the shuffling(e.g if we execute reduceByKey) in Spark ends, or does Spark just read the data into memory without changing the partitions?

Comment: or SPARK just reads the data into memory without changing the partitions?

Comment: Yes, it does changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original RDD remains unchanged (it is immutable). The shuffle process reads the data in each partition and creates different buffers for the different hash values of the key. Then new partitions are created so that each partition reads all the buffers belonging to one or more hash bucket. The result is that the new RDD has new partitions which contain pieces from the multiple original partitions.

Comment: Thanks. RDD in Scala are mutable and it is immutable in python. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I did the below in spark-shell> 
val a = Array(1,2,3)
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(a)

After this I made changes to my Array as
a(0)=6
now when I printed my RDD, it displayed the changed value.

Comment: I would say that this is because of some lazy evaluation somewhere. After printing rdd1, try to change a(0) to 7 and print the rdd again. It should still have the 6